# Nodemailer doesn't send emails, and doesn't return an error message

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I would like to know why nodemailer isn't sending emails, but it isn't returning any errors so I don't know what to do. Here's my code (pretty much copied from the nodemailer documentation):

```
var cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://davidmichael.me',
    allowedHeaders: 'accept, content-type',
    methods: 'GET, POST'
};

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.options('/email', cors(corsOptions));
    app.post('/email', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res){
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'my-email',
                pass: 'my-password'
            }
        });

        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'David Michael <my-email>',
            to: 'recipient-email',
            subject: 'Just verifying your email address ✔',
            text: 'Hello to myself!',
            html: '<p><b>Hello</b> to myself</p>'
        };
        var emailMessage = "";

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if(error){
                emailMessage = "there was an error :-(, and it was this: " + error.message;
            }else{
                emailMessage = "Message sent: " + info.response;
            }
        });
        //transporter.close();
        return res.json({
            message: "success",
            email: emailMessage
        });
    });
};
```

Every time I try it, it successfully returns the JSON object at the end as follows:

```
{"message":"success","email":""}
```

Perhaps I should note that I am using CORS because I want to take the user's email address. My client-side app sends a HTTP POST request with a JSON object containing their email address -- however, the current code doesn't do anything with that yet. I want to get the basic mechanism working first.

I am using Openshift. Could that make a difference?

Also, I have tried using non-Gmail email addresses, and the same thing happens.

Any ideas about where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're returning your JSON response before the asynchronous method returns.  Try putting the response inside the callback:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            emailMessage = "there was an error :-(, and it was this: " + error.message;
        }else{
            emailMessage = "Message sent: " + info.response;
        }
        return res.json({
          message: "success",
          email: emailMessage
        });
    });
    //transporter.close();
```

You may not want to use this in practice though.  Waiting for emails to send can be time-consuming and I suspect you'd see lots of timeouts.  This should get you in the right direction though!

This also assumes your email address is all set up and you've entered real recipients as well. I know I had issues with Gmail because they're really good at detecting bots :)